# Generate coastal line from water tiles

Tags: 2d, algorithm

I have a 2D tiles map. Some tiles are water (black tiles on image). I can compute which tiles are coastal when it's 4 neighbors are not water (black dots on image).

[image: tile grid]

I would like to compute coastal line from these coastal tiles coordinates. How can I achieve that ?

Edit : Representation of goal :

[image: line from points]

So, line coordinates here could be : [(3,1), (2,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), ..., (4,2), (3,1)]

Comment: Can you describe (or show) what the desired output of this process should be?

Comment: @DMGregory Hi, good idea, I edited the question with it.

Comment: So you want to take these edge tiles and put them in a sequence around the perimeter of a polygon? [You should be able to adapt the method shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185751/39518), just using the square grid instead of a hex.

Comment: I will take a look and try it, thanks !

Comment: Why is 3/9 (and maybe 4/9) a costal tiles? There is no water close (or it is not really consistent for one corner touches

Comment: @Zibelas I consider coastal tile when tile "4 neighbors are not all water". But, If you have suggestion about other algorithm I take it :)